# Controller action not supporting the view

Tags: php, zend-framework

It's my first time I am using zend studio. I am working on existing php application and successfully running on server. I am trying to add the new view in the application under specific folder. For this first I am appending the controller to add a new action and created the new view with same name. Unfortunately the controller action is unable to display the view.

Here is my controller code.

```
public function testAction() {      

    mysqli_close($this->db);
}
```

I am not passing any variables in my controller action because my view is php free code. I don't need any variable from action on my view. I am redirecting to view using this code.:
url(array('controller'=>'dashboard', 'action' => 'test', 'brand'=>$this->escape('nrgrs')),'default',true) ?>">

Unfortunately my redirection fails when I click on the link. Any idea?

Thanks,
Ashnav

Comment: What error appears? No controller found or no view found?

Comment: Thanks for replying back. It displays the blank page.

Comment: I think you need to enable displaying errors. In application.ini (config folder) you should change `phpSettings.display_startup_errors`, `phpSettings.display_errors`, `resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions` to 1